# Secure openssl MariaDB - PhpMyAdmin on public server

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I use Nginx for my webserver, and have MariaDB installed with PhpMyAdmin as webgui. The server which it runs is public, and not a private local ip home server. I have also binded a domain to this server. To run everything, I've chosen to use Docker containers. Everything is setting up really well from getting images and so ever. At the moment, I have Nginx working with my main domain and subdomains. Surely, I came at a breakpoint. I wanted, for my (remote) connection to PhpMyAdmin to use tls certificates between PMA itself and MariaDB. In this case, it is needed for PMA to let me know that it is secured. So, that this message is gone:

[image: this message is gone]

And after the login, under database as Server Connection: SSL not being used - that also changes.

But, the important thing is that I have a my.cnf for my MariaDB instance. In that file, I have a couple lines of what's needed:

```
[mysqld]
### MySQL Server ###
## Securing the Database with ssl option and certificates ##
ssl = true
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
ssl-cipher = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

My cert files are correctly in that path, and inside the MariaDB container listed with the cipher:

[image]

But, it says yes for the have_openssl and for the have_ssl that it is disabled. I've done research about this problem in the past days and I cannot get it to work properly. Also, I checked the permissions on the files and made sure there are execute rights. I readed somewhere else that in normal situation without the containers, it needs the permissions set to be for the mysql user. Since I do not have a mysql user, do I ask if it is needed to make one.

How can I fix this issue, that MariaDB has 'have_ssl' on yes and it is configured right? Also, if MariaDB is set up. Do I need to fill in the config for PMA with the files or?